# Azure DevOps: Track build status for commits in mutliple repositories pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, pipeline

I have a [multi-repo pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops)

Can azure track build status for commits for repositories other than the *self* repo that contains the `azure-pipelines.yaml` file?

Ie, when a commit is built in another pipeline status badge is not shown:

[image: Azure commit tree view with status badges]